# Suppress a package when running Android Lint

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, lint

I am using Maven and Jenkins to build an Android app, and I want to use Lint to find code problems. How do I run Lint with a flag in lint.xml suppressing all warnings in dependencies?

Thanks
Markus

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Probably best to ask on the adt-dev mailing list.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try my luck there.